# Redirect issue after add to cart in magento2 custom controller

Tags: magento2, addtocart, redirect, redirect-url

I am calling my custom controller for adding the product through the form action.

Below is my controller file.

```
  <?php 

  namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Product;  
  use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;                           
 class AddProduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                 
{
 protected $formKey;
 protected $cart;
 protected $product;
 protected $checkoutSession;
 public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
   \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
   array $data = []) {
   $this->formKey = $formKey;
   $this->cart = $cart;
   $this->product = $product;
   $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
   parent::__construct($context);
  }

 public function execute()
{
 $productId = 1;
 $customPrice = 150;
 $params = array(
  'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
 'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
 'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product
 );

$_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
$this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

 $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
 $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
 $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
  //Enable super mode on the product.
  $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
  $this->cart->save();

   $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setUrl('http://localsite/checkout/cart');
    return $resultRedirect; 
}


public function getProductQuote($product)
{
 $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
 $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
 return $cartItems;
 } 
}
```

After **$this->cart->save();** , I am redirecting to checkout page

So Product is not adding to the cart, Issue exists in Chrome browser. Mozilla it's fine.

I am getting 302 not found status code in the request. May this be the reason

Can anyone look into this and update me, please. Thanks

Comment: 302 is permanent redirect. not found would be 404. 302 is not an error.

Comment: @PhilippSander, yes but it should be 200 is it? for what reason its showing 302 not found ?

Comment: $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

Comment: 302 does NOT mean "not found". quite the opposite: "found and moved Temporarily"

Comment: @PhilippSander, yes because of this, i am not able to add to cart.

Comment: I'm reading your code in this post and I can't find the line `use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;` not even in your constructor

Comment: @PhilippSander, yes it is there, but i forgot to post here, edited my question

Comment: @jafarpinjar try this `$this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl('checkout/cart')`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is right, only you are missing to

> `use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;`

after your namespace declaration
Your code should work with it:

```
<?php 

 namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Product; 

 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

 class AddProduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                 
 {
 protected $formKey;
 protected $cart;
 protected $product;
 protected $checkoutSession;
 public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
   \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
   array $data = []) {
   $this->formKey = $formKey;
   $this->cart = $cart;
   $this->product = $product;
   $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
   parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
  $productId = 1;
  $customPrice = 150;
  $params = array(
  'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
  'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
  'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product
  );

  $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
  $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

  $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
  $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
  $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
  //Enable super mode on the product.
  $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
  $this->cart->save();

   $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
   $resultRedirect->setUrl('checkout/cart');
   return $resultRedirect; 
 }


 public function getProductQuote($product)
 {
  $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
  $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
  return $cartItems;
 } 
}
```

Comment: hi @magefrms, that is already there

Comment: can you try above modified code, because it works for me even in chrome

Comment: yes, but there is no difference, tell me which line is difference here

Comment: after this line `namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Product; ` you have to declare the use of `use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;` which in your code you forgot to include.

Comment: I told na, it is there, but forgot post in question

Comment: okay as you said it was there. I'm sorry I don't know why I can't see it in your code above but anyway it's okay. hope you can resolve the issue

Comment: okay I see ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91057/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-magefms).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to inject `ResultFactory` as you are already extending `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Simply redirect to the cart with `return $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`